# Tiny MCE text content converted to HTML but not displaying correctly on front-end of React app

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, tinymce

I am building a blog using React and Material UI. I have added a TinyMCE rich text field on my add posts page. The Tiny form is  correctly storing the data as HTML into the JSON file; but when I try rendering a specific blog post I am getting the unformatted text with all the HTML tags. How to I turn this data into plain, formatted text(paragraphs, lists, accents) without displaying the HTML tags?

This is the Tiny editor code:

```
<Editor
    init={{
        plugins: 'link image code',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code'
        }}
        value={body}
        onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.getContent())}
/>
```

This is what is displaying in the JSON file, and on the front-end of my post page:

```
<p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial;" data-mce-style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

I tried using this  but it  didn't seem to do anything:

```
.getContent({ format: 'text' })
```

I have checked the docs but they confused me further. I am hoping to be able to do this without another npm package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found HTML-React-Parser NPM package and it fixed the problem.

Here is an example that returns the formatted text:

```
<Typography variant="p">{parse(post.body)}</Typography>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the editors exact id in the getContent command. Example:

`tinymce.get('tiny-react_1648887531667783768027').getContent({ format: 'text' });` returned the editor content when I ran it in in the console on a Tiny in React demo.

More information:

1. I checked on the exact ID that React created for a demo TinyMCE editor I created.
2. I plugged that editor id into a get content command and ran it in the console log. Screen cap:

[image: tinymce ReactGet Content working]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdJuh.jpg

Also these docs might be helpful: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editor/#getContent there's some more demos of the getContent method here.